# what to do to have a retry in this java code

Tags: java

When I type the password without what is required it wont let me retry the password to get an etiquette password. How do I fix this. I don't know if it is a looping thing or something. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int min =8;
    int max=16;
    int digit=0;
    int special=0;
    int upCount=0;
    int loCount=0;
    String password;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter Your Password:");
        password = scan.nextLine();
    if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max){
        for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
            char c = password.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                upCount++;
            }
            if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
                loCount++;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                digit++;
            }
            if(c>=33&&c<=46||c==64){
                special++;
            }
        }
        if(special>=1&&loCount>=1&&upCount>=1&&digit>=1){
            System.out.println(" Password accepted!");
        }

    }

    if(password.length()<min){

        for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
            char c = password.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
                loCount++;
            }
            }

        if(loCount>0){
            System.out.println(" Password must be atleat "+min+" characters");
    }
    }
    else if(password.length()<min&&upCount>1){
        for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
        char c =password.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
            loCount++;
        }
         if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
            upCount++;
        }
        }
        if(loCount>0&&upCount>0){
        System.out.println(" Password must be atleast "+min+" chracters:");
        System.out.println(" You need atleast one digit:");
        System.out.println(" You need atleast one special chracter:");
    }
    }
     if(password.length()>max||password.length()>=max&&upCount>1&&loCount>1&&digit>1){
         System.out.println(" Password is too long.Limit is "+max+" chracters:");
                 System.out.println(" You need atleast one special chracter:");

        }
      if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max&&loCount>0&&upCount>0&&digit>0&&special==0){
         System.out.println(" You need atleast a special chracter");
     }
      if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max&&loCount>0&&upCount>0&&digit==0&&special==0){
         System.out.println(" You need atleast one digit:");
         System.out.println(" You need atleast one special chracter:");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: A [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) would be a good start

Comment: Okay so what will i need to make that work? Will it go in my if statements? @MadProgrammer

Comment: If you want to do something more than once, you're going to want some kind of loop (most likely `do { ...something... } while (somethingIsTrue);`

Comment: Click on the 'do-while' link in the first comment for how to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
password = scan.nextLine();
```

You have added this line only once, hence it won't accept the password again.
Whenever your password validation fails, you'll have to call this again. Some other tips:

All your existing if()s should update one `boolean` field and one message field, e.g. `isPasswordOk` and `passwordMessage`. Then add

```
System.out.println(passwordMessage);

if(!isPasswordOk){
password = scan.nextLine();
}
```